# Phonegap camera on native browser

Tags: cordova, camera

I know the camera access is possible in Phonegap if used with a wrapper application. Will it work if we access from the native browser?

Let me clarify: If I create an HTML page with Phonegap along with associated JS files and access it from the Safari browser in an iPhone (by entering the URL in the browser manually), can that program get access to camera features? I tried with the sample application at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera. But it doesn't work. No response in the browser or in the camera operation. Wondering whether it is possible at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't work, as the Phonegap core, in Java, isn't loaded.

Comment: As @dda says PhoneGap is a combination of JS and a native library. If you don't create a PG app then the native library won't be loaded and you won't be able to access the camera.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation from both of you.